# NFS mount пишет "mount.nfs: No such device"

Tags: linux, debian, centos, mount, nfs

Есть два сервера: CentOS 6.7 и Debian 8.2. Между ними в обе стороны пытаюсь сделать расшаренные папки через NFS. Папка на CentOS (10.129.1.2) замечательно замаунтилась на Debian (10.129.1.3).  А вот в обратную сторону никак не получается – расшарить папку с Debian и замаунтить её на CentOS.

На CentOS `nfs-utils` установил:

```
yum install nfs-utils nfs-utils-lib
```

Папку создал, в `/etc/exports` её прописал:

```
/var/nfstest    10.129.3.2(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

С CentOS её даже видно:

```
# showmount -e 10.129.1.3
Export list for 10.129.1.3:
/var/nfstest 10.129.3.2
```

Но попытки замаунтить `mount -vvv  10.129.1.3:/var/nfstest  /mnt/nfs/nfstest/` терпят неудачу:

```
mount: fstab path: "/etc/fstab"
mount: mtab path:  "/etc/mtab"
mount: lock path:  "/etc/mtab~"
mount: temp path:  "/etc/mtab.tmp"
mount: UID:        0
mount: eUID:       0
mount: no type was given - I'll assume nfs because of the colon
mount: spec:  "10.129.1.3:/var/nfstest"
mount: node:  "/mnt/nfs/nfstest/"
mount: types: "nfs"
mount: opts:  "(null)"
final mount options: '(null)'
mount: external mount: argv[0] = "/sbin/mount.nfs"
mount: external mount: argv[1] = "10.129.1.3:/var/nfstest"
mount: external mount: argv[2] = "/mnt/nfs/nfstest/"
mount: external mount: argv[3] = "-v"
mount: external mount: argv[4] = "-o"
mount: external mount: argv[5] = "rw"
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Apr 10 06:58:43 2016
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=10.129.1.3,clientaddr=10.129.3.2'
mount.nfs: mount(2): No such device
mount.nfs: No such device
```

ЧЯДНТ и как быть?

**Upd.** в логе на клиенте появляется запись:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Could not load /lib/modules/2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64/modules.dep: No such file or directory
```

В папке `/lib/modules` есть:

```
2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64
2.6.32-358.18.1.el6.x86_64
2.6.32-431.23.3.el6.x86_64
2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64
2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux xxx.xxx.com 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 16 20:59:36 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: http://as-pushkin.blogspot.ru/2010_06_13_archive.html - вроде как те же проблемы. В exports все строки актуальные?

Comment: @donRumata в `exports` единственная строка, и по ссылке иная ошибка – `Permission denied`, в то время, как у меня `No such device`

Comment: Ок, а если рядом поднять ещё 1 centos и попробовать связать centos-centos? И 2 дебиана. Просто может какие-то специфичные опции сборки для конкретного дистрибутива были использованы или версии nfsd или ещё что. Выяснить - это проблема между дистрами или внутри одного. Надеюсь уловил мой поток мыслей.

Comment: Ну так сначала локализовать по максимуму проблему надо. Ну лично я бы сначала без кроссдистрибутивности попробовал, а потом дальше копал.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38200/discussion-between-sergiks-and-don-rumata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте при загрузке выбрать ту версию программы *linux*, для которой у вас есть модули в `/lib/modules`.

Comment: Не в курсе, как это сделать. И есть сомнения, что с другим ядром полетит что-то ещё.

Comment: выберите другой пункт при загрузке.

Comment: если требуется именно эта версия программы, то и установите именно эту версию пакета: kernel-2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! В DigitalOcean через их админку можно поменять kernel.